# How do i fire a submit event in server side from the Sitecore SXA form?

Tags: sxa

How do I fire a submit event in server side from the Sitecore SXA form and apply business logic?

I am using Sitecore Form in which i have addded two text box and one button and i want to fire button event and save the textbox data in a list object and then show that data from the list object to a Column Chart how can i achieve that.?

Comment: Please add more details of your current implementation.

Comment: I am using Sitecore Form in which i have addded two text box and one button and i want to fire button event and save the textbox data in a list object and then show that data from the list object to a Column Chart how can i achieve that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Achieve the `Custom Submit` event you have to create your Custom Event please follow the below steps:

1) Add class in your project and Inherit with `SubmitActionBase`

```
public class EmailMe : SubmitActionBase<string>
    {
        public EmailMe(ISubmitActionData submitActionData) : base(submitActionData)
        {
        }

        protected override bool Execute(string data, FormSubmitContext formSubmitContext)
        {
//to get the form values
 foreach (var viewModel in formSubmitContext.Fields)
            {

  PropertyInfo property = postedField.GetType().GetProperty("Value"); //value property
                object postedValue =
                    (object)property != null ? property.GetValue((object)postedField) : (object)null; //get value

                property = postedField.GetType().GetProperty("Title"); //title property

                object postedTitle =
                    (object)property != null ? property.GetValue((object)postedField) : (object)null;//title value
                string title = postedTitle?.ToString();

                var postedFieldName = ((Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.FieldViewModel)postedField).TemplateId;

}
// now you have your form fields values now you can use your logic here

}
}
```

2) once you done with this now you have to add your custom action in your sitecore, follow below image to add Submit Action Template.

[image]

3) When you add new Submit Action Template, give an appropriate name and assign the below values:
[image]

4) once you done this you will find your submit action in Submit actions

[image]

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: its Working fine but The Execute Method is not getting Executed and to achieve that what do i need to do any help would be appreciated Thanx.

Comment: It should work, make sure your class is inherit from `SubmitActionBase` and you have correctly assign the Model as per Point 3

Comment: Point 3 Image doesn't open in my browser can you please make it visible for me so that i can check and will fix the problem.

Comment: If you want to get the path you can follow image 2, here is clear view of image 3 : https://ibb.co/gZQhHwj